# crear y relacionar 2 tablas temporales

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

buen día estoy creando 2 tablas temporales la primera tabla se llama PREGUNTAS

```
CREATE temporary table PREGUNTAS(
idpregunta int auto_increment,
primary key(idpregunta),
pregunta varchar(200)
);
```

la segunda se llama OPCION

```
CREATE temporary table OPCION (
idopcion int auto_increment,
primary key(idopcion), 
opcion varchar(50),
valor int,
foreign key(idpregunta)references PREGUNTAS(idpregunta)
);
```

necesito que la tabla PREGUNTAS tenga relacion con OPCION, lo realize tal y como esta en opcion pero me marca error diciendome que idpregunta no existe en la tabla, espero y puedan ayudarme a corregir.
O es un error por el hecho de ser tabla temporal??.
ESTAS TABLAS LAS REALIZO ANTES DE CERRAR CONEXION.

Comment: Bueno, claro, te falta crear la columna `idpregunta` en la tabla `OPCION`...

Comment: mas alla de que no se si se pueden realizar relaciones entre tablas temporales ( y no encontre rapidamente nada que diga que no se puede), no entiendo la idea de relacionar tablas temporales. si son temporales es justamente para usarlas en un caso particular y tirarlas..

Comment: Tampoco logro encontrar sentido a dos tabla temporales relacionadas, podrías meter todo en una sola, me imagino que se desecha en el mismo instante donde termina el proceso donde se utiliza. Pero más allá de eso, lo que te comenta @Lamak  te falta el campo idpregunta en la tabla OPCION.

Comment: _ESTAS TABLAS LAS REALIZO ANTES DE CERRAR CONEXION._ Y estas tablas dejarán de existir después de cerrar conexión. Además serán sólo accesibles para el usuario que las ha creado. También, cuidado si existen tablas reales con esos nombres, pues si aplicas un `DROP TABLE` a algunas de las tablas temporales y hay una deconexión del usuario, al reconectar podrías estar borrando las tablas reales. Como ya se ha comentado, no tiene sentido crear tablas temporales relacionadas entre sí. Si crees que puedes usar la relación una vez terminada la sesión... no es posible.

Answer (score 1):

El error es por esta línea tuya:

```
foreign key(idpregunta)references PREGUNTAS(idpregunta)
```

Prueba con:

```
CREATE temporary table OPCION (
idopcion int auto_increment,
primary key(idopcion), 
idpregunta int,
opcion varchar(50),
valor int,
foreign key(idpregunta) references PREGUNTAS(idpregunta)
);
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Revisando la [documentación de MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) vemos que **no es posible asignar llaves foráneas a las tablas temporales**:

> Foreign keys definitions are subject to the following conditions:
>
> - Foreign key relationships involve a parent table that holds the
>     central data values, and a child table with identical values pointing
>     back to its parent. The FOREIGN KEY clause is specified in the child
>     table. The parent and child tables must use the same storage engine.
>     They must not be TEMPORARY tables.
> - ...

---

> Las definiciones de claves externas están sujetas a las siguientes
>   **condiciones**:
>
> - Las relaciones de clave externa implican una tabla primaria que
>     contiene los valores de datos centrales y una tabla secundaria con
>     valores idénticos que señalan de nuevo a su matriz. La cláusula
>     FOREIGN KEY se especifica en la tabla secundaria. Las tablas padre y
>     secundario deben utilizar el mismo motor de almacenamiento. **No deben
>     ser tablas TEMPORALES**.
> - ...

Es decir que aunque aplicases la sintaxis correcta para llaves foráneas en tablas temporales:

```
CREATE temporary table PREGUNTAS(
idpregunta int auto_increment,
primary key(idpregunta),
pregunta varchar(200)
);

CREATE temporary table OPCION (
idopcion int auto_increment,
    idpregunta INT,
primary key(idopcion), 
opcion varchar(50),
valor int,
foreign key(idpregunta)references PREGUNTAS(idpregunta)
);
```

Tendrás derecho al error siguiente:

> Cannot add foreign key constraint